# How to get a local path of file from input file in angular7?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

How can I get the local path of the file from input in HTML?

By the code below I received

> 'C:\fakepath\fileTest.txt'

I need a local path to send to my controller in .netcore web API because I have to create a uploaded file on the backend.

My **.ts**

```
fileChanged(e) {
    this.file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log('name of file' + this.file.name); // name of file
    console.log('path of file' + e.target.value); // path of file
}

uploadDocument(file) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    console.log(fileReader.result);
};
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
    console.log('sadasdas' + file);
}
```

My **.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="my-0">Attachements</p>
      <input type="file" (change)="fileChanged($event)" class="btn btn-secondary" appBootstrapErrors [formControlName]="formControlNames.ATTACHEMENTS">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant get the file path of a file from an user system for security reasons.

Comment: Ok. So how can I send the file to my controller? My controller has parameter with DTO which has a prop like IFormFile Attachements {get;set;}. How can I send the file by input in HTML in angular7?

Comment: You need to create a FormData and append the file to it, then you can send your file to your backend